# Shell command loop on variable and print to file

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Im new to bash script and I need to provide some start condition and loop on it and print it to txt file

e.g. (this is what I need at the end abc from 0 to 1000)

```
    var pre = 'abc'
    var start = '0000'
    var stop = '1000'
    print_to = file.txt
```

The content of the text file should look like:

```
abc0000
abc0001
abc0002
...
abc0100
...
abc1000
```

I've tried with the following but it doesn't work...any idea how can I improve it?

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -uo pipefail


pre="abc"
start="0000"
stop="1000"
file="myfile.txt"

for i in "$pre"+="$start" += 1
do
 echo "$pre"+"$start" + 1 >> $file
done
```

Comment: This might help: [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/74329)

Comment: What do you mean by *doesn't work*?

Comment: @Blasanka - It doesnt print the file the values I needed

Comment: You should really start with finding a bash tutorial. The "+" symbol you're using is neither a concatenation operator nor an addition operator in that context

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [seq -f](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/seq.1.html) to achieve what you are trying to do.

Using `%04` will pad your value up to 4 `0`s.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -uo pipefail

pre="abc"
start=0
stop=1000
file="myfile.txt"

for i in $(seq -f "%04g" $start $stop)
do
  echo $pre$i >> $file
done
```

Comment: Why does `seq -f` use "%g" instead of "%d" for integers?

Answer (score 2):

This is the "tweaked" answer to your question.

```
pre="abc"
start="0000"
stop="1000"
file="myfile.txt"
i=0
while [[ $i -le 1000 ]]
do
  printf "%s%04d\n" "$pre" "$i"
  let i=i+1
done > "$file"
```

This is the simplest way to create that file:

```
printf "%s\n" abc{0000..1000} > myfile.txt
```

Comment: i've tried it and it print abc0000 on 16000 lines :)

Comment: I forgot to increment `i`